# Can Dell 15R 7520(Win 8) Special Edition Drive an external LG ultrawide monitor?

Tags: dell-inspiron

I'm planning to buy an ultra-wide monitor. Can a Dell laptop connected on hdmi drive the lg ultra wide montitor? Please help me.

Answer (score 0):

Yes. The question would be what that LG monitor is running as a native resolution. Depending on it you will not be able to have it use that native resolution.

In order to figure it out look at the specs of the display and afterwards check the specs of your laptop graphics card. Keep in mind that older HDMI standards will not be able to display 4k or only within certain limits (e. g. 30 Hz).

Comment: How can I check my HDMI standard? My graphics card is amd 7700 with Intel hd 4000. The monitor I'm looking for is LG UM 58.

Comment: Usually you would check the manual or the product specs of the manufacturers website. The [technical specifications](http://downloads.dell.com/Manuals/all-products/esuprt_laptop/esuprt_inspiron_laptop/inspiron-15r-se-7520_reference%20guide_en-us.pdf) lack that information. It also doesn't list a "AMD 7700" configuration. But [this](http://en.community.dell.com/support-forums/laptop/f/3519/t/19500455) might be applicable.

Comment: I checked my hdmi standard and it is v1.4 and it supports up to 4k. I guess this should be fine.  It would be great to know from someone who is using it already.